# Can no longer select "none" lock screen option after factory reset

Tags: nokia-6

Previously I've had my phone (Nokia 6.1 plus running android pie) set to use the "None" lock screen option but after doing a factory reset this option no longer appears. I'm only able to select the swipe, pin, password or pattern options.

I find this extremely infuriating and am probably going to have to buy a new phone if I cant fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

**Things I've already tried:**

- Clearing the credentials.
- Disabling all device admin apps.
- Setting a password and then trying to find the option.
- "hard" resetting the phone through the device recovery menu.
- Removing my google account.

I've searched high and low for a fix for this and nothing works.

Thanks for your time!